# Clustering without aggregation with QGIS Point Displacement

Tags: qgis, point, cartography, clustering

I've seen the following map on [twitter](https://twitter.com/BorisMericskay/status/1236608618058919939) and am looking to create the same effect for point displacement.

I'm familiar with grid and circle point displacement as well as with clusters point to aggregate points into one (depending on the scale) but I'm looking for something in the middle.

> clustering point without aggregation, like bunch of grapes

I am intending to achieve this result:

[image: grapes of points]

How can I perform that in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

To configure point cluster symbology with size dependable on number of points , first, select the Point Cluster Symbology option. Next, edit the Cluster Symbol settings. Remove the Font marker or set its size to 0. Finally, define the size of the Simple Marker using an expression based on the number of merged points, represented by the @cluster_size variable. Since I have in my example a large number of points, I use the logarithmic function to resize the points logarithmically : log (1.5,@cluster_size) .

[image: Cluster Point with different size]

Comment: Many thanks for this approach, it's indeed working well! 
But not completely satisfying as I would like to avoid the cluster effect (sorry, the title is not properly phrased) but just avoid superposition of points. I  know how to create a dorling cartogram using R but look for a solution in QGIS.